# Access html id value in angular

Tags: angular

How to get the id using angular? i cant use direct way calling event because i cant bind (click) event like angular way because i use plugin. so i have to make work around to fire this event, but it seem like i cant get the id and if i use below method it will say undefined.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {

     let _self = this;
     this.datatable.on('m-datatable--on-layout-updated', (event) =>{
        $(_self.elRef.nativeElement).find('.deleteFn').click(() => {
          var agencyId = $(this).attr("id");//jquery method
          console.log(agencyId);
          this.router.navigate(['agency/setup']);
         });
     });
}
```

Comment: Can you post more of the code? Also, you're trying to get the id of an HTML element?

Comment: `var agencyId = $(_self.elRef.nativeElement).find('.deleteFn').attr('id')`

Comment: @Jai, $(_self.elRef.nativeElement).find('.deleteFn').attr('id') works but it only take the id for the first button. it will not get the id that i click. Since datatable got many row, so each row got button. Sory forgot to address that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thank guys for your answer, finally i found the answer, but i change a method a bit.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
     $(document).on('click', '.deleteFn',  ($event) => {
      var id = $event.target.id
      console.log(agencyId);
      this.router.navigate(['agency/setup']);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewChild and elementRef:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';



@ViewChild('controlName') control: any;


<input #controlName id="id_1">


ngAfterViewInit() {
     let _self = this;
     this.datatable.on('m-datatable--on-layout-updated', (event) =>{
        $(_self.elRef.nativeElement).find('.deleteFn').click(() => {
          var agencyId = this.control.nativeElement.id;
          console.log(agencyId);
          this.router.navigate(['agency/setup']);
         });
     });
}
```

Comment: What if that button is dynamically generated by jquery?

Comment: Nowhere but the plugin which is used in this code `datatable` it seemed to me that buttons are getting produced dynamically.

Comment: yeap..the button generated dynamically..that why i cant use @ViewChild